# Magento2 - Is it safe to delete entries for deleted order from inventory_reservation table?

Tags: magento2.4.1

I have **delete** test order data using **Mageplaza Delete Order** plugin.

All of the test orders state was processing. So now I am facing issue with `salabale qty` because of order deletion.

To fix this issue I searched on the google then I found when order get placed magento will reserve qty in `"inventory_reservation"` table against the order placed `SKU`.

When I delete the order the from **Mageplaza Delete Order** plugin `"order_cancelled"` event is not getting added into the reservation table.

Because of this `salable qty` showing wrong and  I am not able to add that item into the cart from store front.

So I want delete such entries from the inventory reservation. So Is it safe to delete the records from `inventory_reservation table`?

Kindly advise Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I never was in such a situation, I think it should be ok to delete them as long as you delete only the reservations of the orders you deleted previously: in the metadata column of the `inventory_reservations` table, you should be sure that the `object_increment_id` is the increment_id of the deleted orders.

I did a test just now and when deleting the reservation, as expected increases the salable quantity by the amount that was decreased in the deleted reservation.

However I would suggest you try with one order and see if the result is the expected one, or try first on a test environment.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Instead of deleting What we did to get rid of this issue we inserted order_canceled records into "Inventory_Reservation" table for those order which are in Processing State Deleted by admin.

Comment: that's good to know! this is indeed a safe approach if you really want to keep the history of initial reservations :) thanks for coming back with the feedback, i am sure this will help other people facing the problem, too! cheers!